# Using dir() in Python recursively to read the hierarchy of a class or module and its descendants

Tags: python, oop

Here is an example of what I want to do

```
import mainmodule
output=dir(mainmodule)
output 
 ['module1'
 'module2'
  ...
   ]
dir(module1.module2)
['class1',
'class2',
...
]
```

Now assume that I want to write a recursive function that will go like this:

```
def printstructure(mod)
  output=dir(mod)
  for i in output:
     print (i)
     printstructure(mod+'.'+i)    #trying to concatenate here to obtain module1.module2
```

The above is going to fail because module is an object (type(mod) is module and i is a string

The question is how do I get the child object (reference to it) when I know its name. Sorry if the question is naive I am learning OOP

Comment: Where is the duplication? If you are referring to the previous question I have tried that but it does not work if you go deeper with one level, or I could not figure our how to use getattribute in this case

Comment: Applying `getattr` to the return value of a previous `getattr` call lets you go deeper in a nested hierarchy: `getattr(getattr(mainmodule, "module2"), "class1")`. Often you'd do this in separate steps (e.g. `mm_module2 = getattr(mainmodule, "module2"); mm_m2_class2 = getattr(mm_module2, "class2")`), perhaps with a chain of recursive function calls handling the different levels.

Comment: yes he is correct as you are. I did not realize that getattr returns the name of a module and you can go with that no need to build the entire path needed when you do this dir(moduleA.moduleB.moduleC)